# How to write a for loop in R with multiple criteria and datetimes

Tags: r, datetime, if-statement, for-loop

I am trying to write a for loop that will subset out data that meets certain criteria. Date/times less than 7 minutes apart that also have two different directions (up&down or down&up), and with a length difference less than 4. This is what the dataset looks like.

### Sample Data

```
>    DateTime  Length  Direction
>    4/3/2014 14:43 90  Up
>    4/3/2014 14:45 92  Down
>    4/3/2014 14:46 97  Up
>    4/3/2014 14:49 199 Up
>    4/3/2014 14:50 200 Up
>    4/3/2014 14:55 202 Down
```

I formatted the date:

```
data$DateTime<-as.POSIXlt(data$DateTime,format="%m/%d/%y %H:%M",tz="US/Pacific")
```

I was thinking I could use difftime in a for loop to calculate the time differences and then have additional if statements for the other criteria but I am having trouble setting it up.
Can anyone provide any help?

Answer (score 1):

This is a good example of when a `for` loop would be fine but vectorization is faster and arguably simpler.

With your dataset, it's a little difficult to really check it, since everything but your first row matches your criteria (as all rows are either less than 4 minutes diff or toggling direction).

Starting with your data:

```
data <- data.frame(
    DateTime = strptime(c("04/03/2014 14:43", "04/03/2014 14:45", "04/03/2014 14:46", "04/03/2014 14:49", "04/03/2014 14:50", "04/03/2014 14:55"), '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'), 
    Length = c(90L, 92L, 97L, 199L, 200L, 202L),
    Direction = c("Up", "Down", "Up", "Up", "Up", "Down"))
```

### Base functions

First, `difftime` expects two separate arguments, so unlike `diff`, we need to be explicit. Fortunately, it accepts two vectors and not just two values, so we can use negative `n` for `head` and `tail` (see `help(head)`). (This could also be accomplished easily by converting the dates with `as.numeric` but I thought you'd prefer to keep the classes.)

```
(minutesDiff <- c(Inf, difftime(tail(data$DateTime, n = -1),
                                head(data$DateTime, n = -1),
                                units = 'mins')))
## [1] Inf   2   1   3   1   5

(dirToggle <- c(FALSE, tail(data$Direction, n = -1) != head(data$Direction, n = -1)))
## [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

## these meet your criteria
which((minutesDiff < 4) | ((minutesDiff < 7) & dirToggle) )
## [1] 2 3 4 5 6
```

You said "filtering out" which could be interpreted either way, but it's easy enough to switch.

```
data[(minutesDiff < 4) | ((minutesDiff < 7) & dirToggle), ]
##              DateTime Length Direction
## 2 2014-04-03 14:45:00     92      Down
## 3 2014-04-03 14:46:00     97        Up
## 4 2014-04-03 14:49:00    199        Up
## 5 2014-04-03 14:50:00    200        Up
## 6 2014-04-03 14:55:00    202      Down

data[! ((minutesDiff < 4) | ((minutesDiff < 7) & dirToggle)), ]
##              DateTime Length Direction
## 1 2014-04-03 14:43:00     90        Up
```

### With `dplyr`

If you're adventurous and want to play with `dplyr`, that could work something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
    mutate(minutesDiff = c(Inf, difftime(tail(data$DateTime, n = -1),
                                         head(data$DateTime, n = -1),
                                         units = 'mins')),
           dirToggle = c(FALSE, tail(Direction, n = -1) != head(Direction, n = -1))) %>%
    filter(((minutesDiff < 7) & dirToggle) | (minutesDiff < 4)) %>%
    select(DateTime, Length, Direction)
##              DateTime Length Direction
## 1 2014-04-03 14:45:00     92      Down
## 2 2014-04-03 14:46:00     97        Up
## 3 2014-04-03 14:49:00    199        Up
## 4 2014-04-03 14:50:00    200        Up
## 5 2014-04-03 14:55:00    202      Down
```

(If you want to see the `mutate`d columns in-place, just remove the `select` clause at the end.)

Comment: the problem with using vectorization is that it only compares each date time with the next date time in the sequence. I need to compare each date time with each date time in the data set. For example the first time of 14:45 would have a time difference of 1,4,5, and 10 minutes from each of the other times in the data set. Is it possible to do that with vectors or do I need a for loop?